# Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(NotesApiPage)}") throw error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: maui

I am using viewmodel to navigate to a page upon successful login:
I am getting null reference error when navigating to a different page.
The same line of code that navigates to Login page in cse of no authentication works pretty well.

ViewModel

```
using Notas.Helpers;
using Notas.Model;
using Notas.View;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Notas.ViewModel
{
    public partial class LoadingPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public LoadingPageViewModel()
        {
            CheckUserLoginDetails();
        }

        private async void CheckUserLoginDetails()
        {
            // retrieve token from internal storage
            var token = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("Token");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                await GoToLoginPage();
            else
            {
                var jsonToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(token);
                if (jsonToken.ValidTo < DateTime.UtcNow)
                {
                    SecureStorage.Remove("Token");
                    await GoToLoginPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    var role = jsonToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(j => j.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Role))?.Value;
                    App.UserInfo = new UserInfo()
                    {
                        username = jsonToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Name))?.Value,
                        role = role
                    };
                    MenuBuilder.BuildMenu();
                    await GoToMainPage();
                }

            }
        }

        private async Task GoToLoginPage()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(LoginPage)}");
        }
        private async Task GoToMainPage()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(NotesApiPage)}"); //GETTING ERROR HERE...
        }
    }
}
```

XAML Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Notas.View.NotesApiPage"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Notas.Model"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Notas.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:NotesApiViewModel"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" Padding="5" Spacing="10" Margin="5">
        <Label Text="My Notes" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Subtitle"/>
        <RefreshView 
            IsRefreshing="{Binding Isrefreshing}"
            Command="{Binding GetNotesCommand}">
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Note">
                        <Grid Padding="3" ColumnSpacing="2" ColumnDefinitions="*,Auto">
                            <Frame Grid.Column="0">
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:NotesViewModel}}, Path=GetNoteDetailsCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Label Text="{Binding NoteDescription}"/>
                            </Frame>
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Delete"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:NotesViewModel}}, Path=DeleteNoteCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </RefreshView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

AppShell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="Notas.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Notas.View"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">
    
    <ShellContent
        Title="Home" Icon="icons_home.png"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoadingPage}"
        Route="LoadingPage" />
  
</Shell>
```

AppShel.xaml.cs

```
using Notas.View;

namespace Notas;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(NotesApiPage), typeof(NotesApiPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(NoteDetailPage), typeof(NoteDetailPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LoginPage), typeof(LoginPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
    }
}
```

Getting the below error as shown in screenshot
[image: Error details]

My project structure is as below

[image: Project structure]

Comment: you need to look at the stack trace to see where the exception is originating

Comment: and/or, try putting a breakpoint in the page/VM you are navigating to and step through it to see if it is throwing the exception

Comment: Can you ensure no exception in NotesApiPage and its ViewModel?

Comment: Thank you all. the problem was caused  by a previous method i was calling prior to navigation. Thanks.